# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') mapping issue when array is empty

Tags: reactjs

i have the following code here where i map data  using map funtion the issue is that when

arrays are empty i get the flowing error

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

i dont want error to occur

```
const Row = ([date, item], index) => {
    return (
      <tr className="gradiantblur" key={date || index}>
        <td style={styles.tdFirst}>{date}</td>

        {columns.map((each, i) => (
          <td key={i} style={styles.td}>
            {item.data &&
              item.data[each] &&
              item.data[each].map((itemByModule, id) => (
                <span key={id}>
                  {itemByModule.submodule}
                  <br />
                </span>
              ))}
          </td>
        ))}

        <td style={styles.td}>
          {item.customs &&
            item.customs.map((each, i) => (
              <span key={i}>
                {each.activity}
                <br />
              </span>
            ))}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  };


  return (
    <table style={{ width: "100%", borderCollapse: "collapse" }}>
      <thead style={{ borderBottom: "5px solid #5c0048" }}>
        <tr className="gradiantblur">
          <th style={styles.th}>Dates</th>
          {columns.map((each) => (
            <th style={styles.th} key={each}>
              {each}
            </th>
          ))}
          <th style={styles.th}>Custom</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>{Object.entries(data).map(Row)}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

show me some method where the ui displayes with out ging the error when there is no data

[image]

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Where `columns` are defined?

Comment: yes  i added screen shot of error @Bar717

Answer (score 2):

First thing to understand is that an empty array (`[]`) is not equal to `undefined`.

An empty array has all methods of arrays, while `undefined` doesn't.

There are a few ways to to get around the problem:

1. doing a `columns && columns.map(...`, shows nothing whenever your array is `undefined`, but maps through it whenever it is an array.
2. doing a `columns ? columns.map(...   :   <div>no Data</div>`, maps through array if it is truthy, otherwise shows other elements.
3. doing a `(columns ?? []).map(...`, always maps through an array, but actually first checks if `columns` is `undefined`, if it is, replaces it with an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

Your `columns` is first undefined (before you set it with an other value). Instead of that, you should set it as an empty array initialy, like this:

```
const [columnns, setColumns] = useState([])
```

This way it will not be undefined